# How to fix "Type mismatch. Required: java.lang.String Found: kotlin.String"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm following this https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/ tutorial to run Spring Boot Application with Kotlin. But I have a problem in File "settings.gradle.kts".

The problem:

Type mismatch.
Required: java.lang.String
Found: kotlin.String

By

```
rootProject.name = "api-gateway"
```

In build.gradle.kts I have written this:

```
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: hard to know it but... can you try doing something like this? tasks.withType(KotlinCompile::class.java).all {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it so:

Rename the **settings.gradle.kts** File to **settings.gradle**